# Onclick undefined var

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have the following code in my website

```
@if(count($alleSpiele) > 0)
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Spiel auswählen</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="spielAuswahl" name="spielAuswahl">
            @foreach($alleSpiele as $alleSpieleOutput)
                <option value="{!! $alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft !!}">{{$alleSpieleOutput->heimmannschaft}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
@endif

<script>
    $('#spielAuswahl').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });

</script>
```

When I go to my website I get the output in the console...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):23
```

What is my mistake? Is something missing?

Comment: Have you imported JQuery correctly?

Comment: do you have jquery referenced on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't imported the jQuery library into your page. You could test quickly this by getting the appropriate version of jQuery from a CDN(Content Delivery Network) like https://code.jquery.com. Simply add a new `<script>` tag and load the content inside the `<head>` tags and refresh the page to see if the error persists.

e.g. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>`

If after doing this you are still seeing errors, then there are bigger issues.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the jquery script referenced in the head of of your document.

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <script src="[path to jquery.js]"></script>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime if you want to use jquery.. make sure you include jquery js. Download [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js).. and put it on your public js path. then include it in your layout

```
<head>
    {{ Html::style('material/assets/css/style.css') }}
</head>
<body>

//your blade content html

<script>
    {{ Html::script('material/assets/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js') }}

    $('#spielAuswahl').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });

</script>
</body>
```